# Maintain different version and build number for Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, version

I am working on a Flutter app and the android version of the app was released in play store 2 months ago. Since then I have pushed a around 15 updates to the app. But I haven't release the app on app store yet.
The version and build number of the android app is:

```
version:1.0.13+15
```

Now I wish to publish the same app on the app store and maintain the same codebase. Is there any possible way to assign version number and build number only to iOS? I want to publish the app on iOS starting with the version number `1.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building the release version for a Flutter app, you can pass the `--build-name` and `--build-number` arguments to override the `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` for iOS correspondingly, e.g:

`flutter build ios --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=1.0.0`

`build-number` is used for the internal app version, but you can just set it to the same value. For more info about these arguments, check the documentation (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios) or run `flutter build ios -h` in your terminal.